# The Web Server Failed with status code 200, OK | Unable to start process dotnet.exe

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I want to start my webapplication, but following error is poping up.

[image]

The error beginned to appear after adding some services to asp.net core services. But i don't know if i did something other before or after that.

This is what i added:

`services.Configure<ConnectionStringSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Database"));
            services.AddDbContext<StreamworkerContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get<ConnectionStringSettings>().ConnectionString));`

What i've tried so far:

- Restart Visual Studio
- Restart Windows
- Delete Visual Studio Cache

**Createing a new project fixed this bug.**

**If i select to start with IIS Express it is not working, but if i select the projectname, it works also. But then i cannot debug.**

If i am looking in the file

> C:\Users\nikla\AppData\Local\Temp\HttpFailure_07-28-24.html

the file is like a correctly working request.

IIS Express Logs:

> ## Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
>
> ## Version: 1.0
>
> ## Date: 2017-05-22 18:32:35
>
> ## Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username > c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus
>
> sc-win32-status time-taken 2017-05-22 18:32:35 ::1 DEBUG / - 56368 -
>   ::1 - - 301 0 0 7